# How to use linq to find the minimum

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `class A { public float Score; ... }` and an `IEnumerable<A> items` and would like to find the `A` which has minimal score.

Using `items.Min(x => x.Score)` gives the minimal score and not the instance with minimal score.

How can I get the instance by iterating only **once** through my data?

**Edit**: So long there are three main solutions:

- Writing an extension method (proposed by Svish). *Pros*: Easy to use and evaluates Score only once per item. *Cons*: Needs an extension method. (I choosed this solution for my application.)
- Using Aggregate (proposed by Daniel Renshaw). *Pros*: Uses a built-in LINQ method. *Cons*: Slightly obfuscated to the untrained eye and calls evaluator more than once.
- Implementing IComparable (proposed by cyberzed). *Pros*: Can use Linq.Min directly. *Cons*: Fixed to one comparer - can not freely choose comparer when performing the minimum computation.

Comment: Not quite. Knowing the index does not help directly for IEnumerable. In some cases one must iterate again using the index to find the desired instance.

Comment: .NET 6 now supports `items.MinBy(x => x.Score)`, see the duplicate for details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at the **MinBy** extension method in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.github.io/) (created by Jon Skeet, now principally maintained by Atif Aziz).

- [MinBy documentation](http://morelinq.github.io/2.2/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MinBy__2.htm)
- [MinBy source code](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/v2.0.0/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) (it's pretty straightforward and has no dependencies on other files).

Comment: Couldn't the whole of the body of that method be replaced with this?  return source.Aggregate((c, d) => comparer.Compare(selector(c), selector(d)) < 0 ? c : d);

Comment: @Daniel: You'd have to ask Jon Skeet about that :p Some of it is error checking though, which you of course want to have in a library like that.

Comment: I see the slight difference, that in MinBy the selector is called only once per instance, while with Aggregate it is called more often.

Comment: Btw.: The MinBy<> operator is also supported by Rx (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx)

Answer (score 76):

Use Aggregate:

```
items.Aggregate((c, d) => c.Score < d.Score ? c : d)
```

As suggested, **exact** same line with more friendly names:

```
items.Aggregate((minItem, nextItem) => minItem.Score < nextItem.Score ? minItem : nextItem)
```

Comment: Interesting answer. It is quite opaque though - If I didn't already know what it was doing I would be quite confused as to the intention of that code.

Comment: Jamie: I agree, it meets Danvil's requirements but it can be difficult to parse for those not familiar with functional languages like Hakell or F#.

Comment: @Jamie - not when the line starts with `minItem = `. It is a bit problematic because you re-implement `Min`, but I think that's a minor point.

Comment: This is nice :) It uses only linq and iterates only once.

Comment: Some new to LINQ may find using more meaningful variable names helpful to understanding what's going on here: `items.Aggregate((minItem, nextItem) => minItem.Score < nextItem.Score ? minItem : nextItem)`.

Comment: Here's .NET Framework 4.5 [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this overload of the `Aggregate` method. The example shows how to use `Aggregate` to reverse the order of items in an array of `string`s.

Answer (score 23):

Try `items.OrderBy(s => s.Score).FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: Succinct, but be cautious of sorting; it's a "slow" operation. I would recommend benchmarking if the number of elements is large to make sure performance is acceptable.

Comment: This does not iterate only once! It is O(n log n) and not O(n).

Comment: Check Svish's answer. I was about to write an extension method that did exactly what Jon Skeet has already done.

Comment: RE: "This does not iterate only once!" That is true. But it does answer the question that brought me to this page: "How to use linq to find the minimum." And, yes, one will pay a price when ordering a large collection of items.

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved with a little simple iteration:

```
float minScore = float.MaxValue;
A minItem = null;

foreach(A item in items)
{
   if(item.Score < minScore)
       minItem = item;
}

return minItem;
```

It's not a nice LINQ query, but it does avoid a sorting operation and only iterates the list once, as per the question's requirements.

Comment: Of course. And I would like to know if this pattern can be expressed with linq ...

Comment: The answer is, no LINQ does not offer a `MinItem` operation. You can wrap my answer in an extension method if you wish to have something equally succinct. Alternatively, you can do it with LINQ if you make two passes of the list.

Comment: just a note that the line
minItem = item;
should be
{
minItem = item;
minScore = item.Score;
}

Answer (score 4):

The quick way as I see it would be implementing IComparable for your class A (if possible ofcourse)

```
class A : IComparable<A>
```

It's a simple implementation where you write the `CompareTo(A other)` have a look at [IEnumerable(of T).Min on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352408%28VS.90%29.aspx) for a reference guide

Comment: This is a good idea. But what if I had Score1 and Score2 and would like to change what score I use for finding the minimum?

Comment: Hmm well it depends...somehow I wouldn't mind having the object knowing what defines it's comparison base, but I can see the concept of why you would like it the other way around. I would say the Jon Skeet way would be obvious with MinBy

Answer (score 3):

A little fold should do:

```
var minItem = items.Aggregate((acc, c) => acc.Score < c.Score? acc : c);
```

Ah... too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Jamie Penney got my vote.  You can also say

```
items.OrderBy(s => s.Score).Take(1);
```

Which has the same effect.  Use Take(5) to take the lowest 5 etc.

Comment: Sorting does not iterate only *once*!

Comment: RE: "Sorting does not iterate only once!" That is true. But it does answer the question that brought me to this page: "How to use linq to find the minimum." And, yes, one will pay a price when ordering a large collection of items.