# Min tuple in IGrouping of tuples

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, min

I have multiple points, and multiple polygons that contain points.  I need to match a point to the smallest-area polygon that contains it.

What I get out of the database is a `List<(string poly_name, Point point, double area)>`.

So I started by doing `list.GroupBy(t=>t.point)`, which gives me a nice `IGrouping<Point, (string, Point, double)`.

Now I want to get the smallest area polygon from each group.  Linq's `Min()` function doesn't allow me to pull the whole tuple; only the smallest area.  How can I get the whole tuple?

Comment: It feels like this is really a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736236 - the fact that you have groupings and a tuple is somewhat irrelevant; you're still trying to get "the element with the minimum value" from a sequence.

Comment: The grouping part is what meant that I couldn't apply another answer to my problem.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, I'm afraid. If you could provide a [mcve], and show what you've tried (including research into similar questions) that would help us provide a more useful answer, and it would make the question more useful too.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with *an* answer while I was writing this question, but I thought it might be useful to someone else.  And I'm interested in finding out if the community has a better solution.

```
list.GroupBy(t => t.point).Select(g => g.OrderBy(t => t.area).First())
```

Basically, "group the tuples by point, then for each group, order by area, smallest to largest, and only keep the first tuple of the group".