# minimum value in dictionary using linq

Tags: linq, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary of type

```
Dictionary<DateTime,double> dictionary
```

How can I retrive a minimum value and key coresponding to this value from this dictionary using linq ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

Answer (score 4):

```
var min = dictionary.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Value).First();
var minKey = min.Key;
var minValue = min.Value;
```

This is not very efficient though; you might want to consider [MoreLinq's](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) `MinBy` extension method.

If you are performing this query very often, you might want to consider a different data-structure.

Comment: @Jess: Read the question: "minimum value and *key* coresponding to this value"

Comment: @Jess: Yup. He does say "key" in the singular form.

Comment: Upvoted as I feel this answer gives more readable code than when using the Aggregate method.

Answer (score 4):

### Aggregate

```
var minPair = dictionary.Aggregate((p1, p2) => (p1.Value < p2.Value) ? p1 : p2);
```

Using the mighty `Aggregate` method.

I know that `MinBy` is cleaner in this case, but with `Aggregate` you have more power and its built-in. ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
    Dictionary<DateTime, double> dictionary;
    //...
    double min = dictionary.Min(x => x.Value);
    var minMatchingKVPs = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value == min);
```

You could combine it of course if you really felt like doing it on one line, but I think the above is easier to read.

```
    var minMatchingKVPs = dictionary.Where(x => x.Value == dictionary.Min(y => y.Value));
```

Comment: The one line version has O(n^2) efficiency - it will find the minimum value in the dictionary *on every pair*.

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily do this efficiently in normal LINQ - you can get the minimal value easily, but finding the key requires another scan through. If you can afford that, use Jess's answer.

However, you might want to have a look at `MinBy` in [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) which would let you write:

```
var pair = dictionary.MinBy(x => x.Value);
```

You'd then have the pair with both the key and the value in, after just a single scan.

EDIT: As Nappy says, `MinBy` is also in System.Interactive in [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx).

Comment: never saw MoreLINQ ... looks pretty neat.

Comment: `MinBy` is also part of System.Interactive.dll of the [Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx)