# LINQ Order By to select lowest Index

Tags: linq, sql-order-by

I am relatively new to LINQ and don't know how to do an Order By. I have an IEnumerable list of myObject and want to do something like `select first myObject from myObjectList order by myObject.id asc` How can I accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify this please? Do you *actually* need the ordered results, or just the result with the lowest ID? Do you need the *index* of that entry, or just the ID?

Comment: If you only need the result with the lowest ID, there is an implementation of a MinBy extension method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value). It was written by some fella' I've never heard of though (his name is Jon Skeet, or something like that), so I dunno how much I trust it.

Comment: @Jon...some clarity.  I need the object in the list that has the lowest Id.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ascending is the default order by direction.

```
var query = from myObject in myObjectList
            orderby myObject.id
            select myObject;

Object o = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

If you want descending, you will want to use `orderby myObject.id descending`.

Answer (score 3):

```
var obj = myObjects.OrderBy(o => o.id).First();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348657.aspx) method.

For example:

```
var data = (from o in Orders
           order by o.OrderID
           select o.Name).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the item with the lowest ID, you don't need an OrderBy... It is much faster to just enumerate the list once, since this operation has `O(n)` complexity whereas a typical sort has `O(n log n)` complexity. You can do it with a `foreach` loop, or use an extension method like this one:

```
    public static T WithMin<T, TValue>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TValue> selector)
    {
        var min = default(TValue);
        var withMin = default(T);
        bool first = true;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            var value = selector(item);
            int compare = Comparer<TValue>.Default.Compare(value, min);

            if (compare < 0 || first)
            {
                min = value;
                withMin = item;
            }
            first = false;
        }
        return withMin;
    }
```

Use it like that:

```
var objectWithMinId = myObjectList.WithMin(o => o.Id);
```

Comment: what if the backing store (e.g. SQL) has an index and LINQ can take advantage of that? enumerating the full set is akin to a full table scan.

Comment: @magma, yes, but in this case it was pretty clear that the backing store was an in-memory collection, so I wrote my answer with that in mind. If the backing store is a database, you're better off doing an OrderBy and take the first item.

Comment: in-memory that's a great tip!

Answer (score 0):

Ascending is the default if you wanted the reverse just use `OrderByDescending()`

```
var obj = myObjectList.OrderBy(x => x.id).First();
```

if you needed the ID or some other property from the object you can keep the same line

```
int myID = myObjectList.OrderBy(x => x.id).First().id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should look like following:

```
var yourquery = (from myObject in myObjectList
                 orderby myObject.id
                 select myObject).First();
```

Now the variable yourquery contains the object you require.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer using FirstOrDefault() in place of First() , in case your query does not return any elements then First() will throw a Exception.

```
var myObj = (from myObject in myObjectList orderby myObject.id select myObject).FirstOrDefault();
```