# Linq query to select top records

Tags: c#, linq

I have `IEnumerable<MyData>` which contains following data

```
Fruits | Name | Quantity | 
__________________________
 Mango | Jay  |    10    |
__________________________
 Apple | Jay  |    16    |
__________________________
 Grapes| Jay  |    12    |
__________________________
 Mango | Raj  |    11    |
__________________________
 Apple | Raj  |    20    |
__________________________
 Grapes| Raj  |    3     |
__________________________
 Mango | Vik  |    20    |
__________________________
 Apple | Vik  |    15    |
__________________________
```

I need to select from Linq top two quantity according to name like

```
Jay (10+16+12) = 38
Raj (11+20+3) = 34
Vik (20+15) = 35
```

Jay and Vik have top two quantity sum so I need these records

```
Fruits | Name | Quantity | 
__________________________
 Mango | Jay  |    10    |
__________________________
 Apple | Jay  |    16    |
__________________________
 Grapes| Jay  |    12    |
__________________________
 Mango | Vik  |    20    |
__________________________
 Apple | Vik  |    15    |
__________________________
```

Comment: So just to clarify. You want to sum the quantities per name, find the top two names, and then select the records with those names?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sounds like you might want something like:

```
var query = from item in collection
            group item by item.Name into g
            orderby g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)  descending
            select g;
var topTwo = query.Take(2);
```

That will take the first two *groups*, so you'd use it as:

```
foreach (var group in topTwo)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", group.Key);
    foreach (var item in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  {0}: {1}", item.Fruits, item.Quantity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should that not be orderby desc?

Comment: But you may wish to find the top n results without performing a complete sort on a (potentially much larger) set of m results.

Is there any way for Linq to do this? Thanks, PW

Comment: Ah - I suppose with Lazy-Linq, this is fine - I probably need to remove a few .ToArray()'s elsewhere in my code...

Comment: @PhilWhittington: In LINQ to Objects? Not really - I have an alternative LINQ to Objects implementation which uses a "just-in-time" quicksort, making this sort of thing more efficient than the MS implementation (which *does* do a complete sort before returning anything). In LINQ to SQL etc, it would be up to the database anyway.

Comment: Thank you @JonSkeet- I wasn't aware of that. I once used your MinBy (delegate) Linq extension (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value) a long time ago. I will search for your full Linq alternative; it may be useful as we have a notion of Rank() for search results, but we don't want to sort any but the top 30. Many thanks.

Comment: @PhilWhittington: See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/07/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26d-fixing-the-key-selectors-and-yielding-early.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would work.

```
private static IEnumerable<MyData> GetTop2Names(IEnumerable<MyData> data)
{
    var top2 = data.GroupBy(d => d.Name)
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(d => d.Quantity))
                   .Take(2)
                   .Select(g => g.Key);
    return data.Where(d => top2.Contains(d.Name));
}
```

Step by step

1. Group by Name (as that's what you're summing)
2. Sort by the sum of the quantities
3. Take the top 2 names
4. Select the items from the original list that match those names.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var topTwo = myData.GroupBy(d => d.Name).OrderByDescending(g => g.Sum(d => d.Quantity)).TakeWhile((data,index) => index < 2).SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Should look like this:

```
IEnumerable<MyData> source = new List<MyData>();
var names = source
    .GroupBy(item => item.Name)
    .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Sum(i => i.Quantity))
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Value)
    .Select(item => item.Key)
    .Take(2);

var result = source.Where(item => names.Contains(item.Name));
```