# find the minimum of a set of results stored in an array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, class

My program has textboxes and a listView and info is typed into the textboxes and then displayed into the listview at the click of a button. the info is ID, first name, last name and yearly salary. The info is stored in array.

I want to find the person with the lowest salary. How do I go about doing this? (in C#)

this is my Form1:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Collections;


    namespace Employee_Program
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {


            public Form1()
            {
        em = new ArrayList();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ArrayList em = new ArrayList();


    private void show_employee()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        foreach(Employee a in em)
        {
            int i = listView1.Items.Count;
            listView1.Items.Add(a.EmployeeId.ToString());
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(a.FirstName);
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(a.LastName);
            listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Add(a.YearSalary.ToString());


        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Employee a = new Employee();
        a.EmployeeId = float.Parse(employeeId.Text);
        a.FirstName = firstName.Text;
        a.LastName = lastName.Text;
        a.YearSalary = float.Parse(yearSalary.Text);
        em.Add(a);
        show_employee();


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    // this is the button that will return the lowest salary value. Preferably in a                        
    //message box? Any idea?

        }
    }}
```

this is my class, Employee:

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;

       namespace Employee_Program
       {
class Employee
{
    protected float employeeId;
    protected string firstName;
    protected string lastName;
    protected float yearSalary;


    // first constructor
    public Employee()
    {
        employeeId = 0;
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        yearSalary = 0;
    }

    // second constructor
    public Employee(float EmployeeId, string FirstName,
                           string LastName, float YearSalary) 
    {
        employeeId = EmployeeId;
        firstName = FirstName;
        lastName = LastName;
        yearSalary = YearSalary;
    }

    public float EmployeeId
    {
        get
        {
            return employeeId;
        }

        set
        {
            employeeId = value;
        }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get
        {
            return firstName;
        }

        set
        {
            firstName = value;
        }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName;
        }

        set
        {
            lastName = value;
        }
    }

    public float YearSalary
    {
        get
        {
            return yearSalary;
        }

        set
        {
            yearSalary = value;
        }
    }


           }

       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider about refactoring your code.

- you can use [chain constructors](http://geekswithblogs.net/kaju/archive/2005/12/05/62266.aspx) to avoid initialization duplication
- you can use [auto-properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)
- its very strange that you use float as id. consider using something like int
- usually camelCase used for parameters naming
- consider using decimal type for salary

Your Employee class is much cleaner now:

```
public class Employee
{   
    public Employee()
        : this(0, "", "", 0)
    {
    }

    public Employee(int employeeId, string firstName,
                           string lastName, decimal yearSalary) 
    {
        EmployeeId = employeeId;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        YearSalary = yearSalary;
    }

    public int EmployeeId  { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set;}
    public decimal YearSalary { get; set; }
}
```

- consider using NumericUpDown control for numeric values input
- consider using descriptive names for controls
- consider adding new employee to the end of listView, instead of reloading all employees
- consider using generic list for employees collection
- usually PascalCase used for methods naming

Here is Form1 code:

```
private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

private void ShowEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    var item = employeeListView.Items.Add(employee.EmployeeId.ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(employee.FirstName);
    item.SubItems.Add(employee.LastName);
    item.SubItems.Add(employee.YearSalary.ToString());
}

private void AddEmployeeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.EmployeeId = (int)idNumericUpDown.Value;
    employee.FirstName = firstNameTextBox.Text;
    employee.LastName = lastNameTextBox.Text;
    employee.YearSalary = salaryNumericUpDown.Value;
    employees.Add(employee);
    ShowEmployee(employee);
}

private void LowestSalaryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal minSalary = employees.Min(em => em.YearSalary);
    MessageBox.Show(minSalary.ToString("C"), "Min salary");
}
```

Comment: the only problem i'm having is this part: "Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.EmployeeId = (int)idNumericUpDown.Value;
    employee.FirstName = firstNameTextBox.Text;
    employee.LastName = lastNameTextBox.Text;
    employee.YearSalary = salaryNumericUpDown.Value;
    employees.Add(employee);
    ShowEmployee(employee);" it doesn't like the idNumericUpDown and the salaryNumericUpDown

Comment: @user1336868 thats two controls of type `NumericUpDown` which provide input for numeric values. You can still use TextBox, but you will have to handle incorrect input.

Comment: @user1336868 just replace `yearSalary` and `employeeId` textboxes. Drag two NumericUpDown controls from ToolBox to your form. And name them `idNumericUpDown` and `salaryNumericUpDown`.

Comment: ok I tried all of this but the program won't work. When I click the button nothing happens?

Comment: @user1336868 you need to assign `AddEmployeeButton_Click` to button1 Click event. `LowestSalaryButton_Click` to button2 Click event. Also consider to rename buttons to `addEmployeeButton` and `lowestSalaryButton`.

Comment: tHANK YOU SO MUCH. I am completely new to this and your answer was SO helpful. Thank you again.

Comment: Just wondering, if I wanted the persons full details to come up with the lowest salary how would I go about doing that?

Comment: E.g. `IEnumerable<Employee> poors = employees.Where(em => em.YearSalary == minSalary);` keep in mind that there could be several employees with same min salary.

Comment: @user1336868 right after you got minSalary value. This statement will return list of employees which have same salary

Comment: so `decimal minSalary = employees.Min(em => em.YearSalary);
            IEnumerable<Employee> poors = employees.Where(em => em.YearSalary == minSalary);
            MessageBox.Show(minSalary.ToString("C"), "Min salary");` ?

Comment: Exactly. When you get list of poor employees, you can do show their details. E.g. `poors.Count()` returns count of employees with min salary. `foreach(var poor in poors) MessageBox.Show(poor.FirstName + poor.LastName)` will show messageboxes with names of all poor people

Comment: so I can't get them all in one messagebox?

Comment: You can show another form with listBox and show poor employees there. Or you can build some string and show that string in MessageBox. Sorry, need to go now

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** Be sure to include:

```
using System.Linq;
```

You can use a LINQ expression such as:

```
Employee[] employees;
//Populate employees   
var min = (from e in employees select e.YearSalary).Min();
```

Comment: "I want to find *the person* with the lowest salary"

Comment: What if more than one person has the lowest salary?

Comment: sorry by Employees is that referring to the class Employee? If so it won't work and is underlined. And yes more than one person with lowest salary has to be considered too, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value

Comment: @user1336868 - Sorry, that referred to your array of Employee objects.  The link above has some details on how to actually select the person or people with the lowest salary.

Answer (score 2):

[MoreLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) has a MinBy method. If you don't want to use MinBy, there are several ways to do it. I recommend this approach:

```
// Don't use an ArrayList, use a List<Employee>
Employee minEmp = employees.Aggregate(float.MinValue, (min, e) => (e.YearSalary < min.YearSalary) ? e : min);
```

If you need a list of all the employees with matching minimum salary, you could do something like this:

```
float min = employees.Min(e => e.YearSalary);
var minEmps = employees.Where(e => e.YearSalary == min);
```

Comment: this seems perfect but how do I get it to accept "employees"? do i declare that somewhere?

Comment: "Don't use an `ArrayList`, use a `List<Employee>`". An `ArrayList` is untyped, which can lead to problems and code smell. And I used `employees` instead of `em`. I think it is more readable.

Comment: I've never used List<Employee> before, so I have to redo the code in that?

Comment: I didn't see any place in your code where you would have to change anything, except for the variable declaration and in the constructor. Docs for `List<>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx BTW, why are you instantiating `em` twice?

Comment: I think it was a mistake, thank you! However, it does not like the use of "e" in "e =>" etc. Why is that?

Comment: Oh, that would be because you already have a local variable named e. you can replace e with emp, or anything, really.

Comment: hmm I tried that but then it suddenly doesn't like YearSalary :/

Comment: Did you do this? `emp => emp.YearSalary == min`

Comment: yes I just did that and NOW it doesn't like the "employees" in "float min = employees.Min(emp => emp.YearSalary);". *facepalm* I'm so sorry but thank you for all this help BTW!

Comment: It doesn't like `employees`? What does it say?

Answer (score 1):

Look into using a `MinBy` extension method. It's notably lacking in Linq. An implementation can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs).

Then you'd simply:

```
Employee aCheapEmployee = employees.MinBy(e => e.Salary);
```

If you need to find all lowest paid employees:

```
var minSalary = employees.Min(e => e.Salary); 
IEnumerable<Employee> slaveLabourers = employees.Where(e => e.Salary==minSalary);
```