# ListView column highest value

Tags: c#

I don't need to sort listView I only need to get highest value from column, all values in that column are numbers.It would be nice if I could cast it to `IEnumerable<int>` somehow then I could use LINQ.

**Update**

My existing code:  DrawArray is array with random numbers.I need to get max value of `index.ToString()` column without creating another list or array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < Rounds; i++)
{
ListViewItem lvItem = new ListViewItem(i.ToString());

lvItem.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lvItem, index.ToString()));

int[] DrawArray = Draw(DrawsPerRound, RoundSize);

lvItem.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lvItem, DrawArray.Aggregate("", (s, t) => s + ", " + t.ToString()).TrimStart(new char[] { ',' })));

lvItem.SubItems.Add(new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(lvItem, "No"));

lvItem.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;

listView1.Items.Add(lvItem);
}
```

Comment: Please post your existing code.

Comment: You can use methods in this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be missing some casts or something, and it is a bit ugly, but here's an idea:

```
var max = listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Max(x => int.Parse(x.SubItems[0].Text));
```

This uses LINQ, so make sure you have `using System.Linq;` in your file and are using .NET >= 3.5.

Comment: Well I tried but I can't acess Max directly I assume it has to be casted first.

Comment: listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>().Max(x => int.Parse(x.SubItems[0].Text));

Comment: Thanks @DanielVlasceanu, I'll put that `Cast` into my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`ListView.Items` is `ListViewItemCollection` inherit of `IList, ICollection, IEnumerable`

By linq, you can get what you want.

```
System.Nullable<int> max = (
              from m in listView1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>() 
              select int.ParseInt(m.SubItems[0].Text)).Max();
```

Comment: Lose the 'var' in your query which souldn't be there, and you will get Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection'.  'Select' not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range variable 'm'.

Comment: You need to explicitly specify (cast to) the type of the variable m whenever the compiler can't infer its actual type. Therefore, listview1.Items.Cast<ListViewItem>() should solve the problem.