# Return row with minimum value using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 classes like this:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public ICollection<ProductTerm> ProductTerms { get; set; }
    // More properties here
}

public partial class ProductTerm
{
    public short ID { get; set; }
    public short MinTermDuration { get; set; }
    // More properties here
}
```

As you will see, Product has a 1 to many relationship with ProductTerm.

I'm trying to return the entire ProductTerm with the Min MinTermDuration. I can get the result I want here but am returning the MinTermDuration - how do I return the whole ProductTerm?

```
    int GetMinTerm()
    {
        return ProductTerms.Min(t => t.MinTermDuration);
    }
```

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can first order your products and then just take the first one on  the top.

```
return ProductTerms.OrderBy(t => t.MinTermDuration).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `OrderBy(...).FirstOrDefault()`, as suggested by Vsevolod Goloviznin; however this approach needs to sort the collection, which has a complexity of `O(n log n)`... The approach suggested by Selman22 is better, but it still enumerates the result twice (which could be an issue if the sequence is an Entity Framework or OData query).

A better option is to use a `MinBy` extension method that just loops over the collection once and returns the item that has the min value, with a complexity of `O(n)`:

```
return ProductTerms.MinBy(t => t.MinTermDuration);
```

You can find such a method in [Linq.Extras](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/Linq.Extras#minby-maxby) or in [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

---

EDIT: the above is true if you're working with an in-memory collection (Linq to Objects), *not* if you're working with a database (using Entity Framework for instance). The DB knows how to find the item with the min value efficiently; using `MinBy` in this case would fetch all rows to examine them, so it would be very inefficient.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework - what would the issue be?

Comment: @dotnetnoob, EF queries implement `IEnumerable<T>`, so it should work fine. However, in this case it's better to use the `OrderBy` approach, because the DB can do it efficiently, whereas using `MinBy` would fetch all rows to examine them...

Comment: Ah, I see. This shouldn't be a problem - there are less than 100 products, each with around 5 terms. The data is retrieved .AsNoTracking and cached prior to any property being requested.

Answer (score 1):

`Min` returns the minimum value, not the item with the value. You can use `First` to get `ProductTerm` that has `MinTermDuration`:

```
ProductTerm GetMinTerm()
{
    var min = ProductTerms.Min(t => t.MinTermDuration);
    return ProductTerms.First(x => x.MinTermDuration == min);
}
```

Another alternative would be using [`MinBy`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs?r=2da75c30d5bda7959e5113b702b4bb204a0e4a2c) method, it requires using a thir-party library but  more straightforward:

```
ProductTerm GetMinTerm()
{
    return ProductTerms.MinBy(t => t.MinTermDuration);
}
```