# c# pulling dara from classes using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a two classes:

```
public class Profile 
{
    private List<Location> location = new List<Location>();
    public int Current { get; set; }
    public List<Location> Location { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Single x { get; set; }
    public Single y { get; set; }
    public Single z { get; set; }
    public float Distance { get; set; }
}
```

What I do is populating those two classes with data I get from XML:

This is XML structure:

```
<start>
    <level Current="2">
        <GPSSpots>
            <GPSSpot id="1" x="78492.61" y="-80973.03" z="-4403.297" Distance="90"/>
            <GPSSpot id="2" x="78323.57" y="-81994.98" z="-4385.707" Distance="55"/>
            <GPSSpot id="3" x="78250.57" y="-81994.98" z="-4385.707" Distance="43"/>
        </GPSSpots>
        <Vendor id = "1" x="123456" y="456789" z="0234324"/>
        <Banker id = "1" x="23432" y="3243243" z="5154445"/>
        <Relocate>
            <Teleporter id = "1" MapID="1122" x="324324" y="23432" z="23432432"/>
            <Teleporter id = "2" MapID="4444" x="324324" y="23432" z="23432432"/>           
            <Teleporter id = "3" MapID="2222" x="324324" y="23432" z="23432432"/>
        </Relocate>
</start>
```

And my XML parser method:

```
public static List<Profile> ParseXml() //Parsing all them GPSSpots from XML
{
    List<Profile> result = new List<Profile>(); //first we have to empty the list in case spawn will be called more than once
    result.Clear();

    doc = XDocument.Load(Document);

    result = (from n in doc.Descendants("level")
              select new Profile()
              {
                  Current = int.Parse(n.Attribute("Current").Value),
                  Location = (from l in n.Element("GPSSpots").Elements("GPSSpot")
                              select new Location()
                              {
                                  id = int.Parse(l.Attribute("id").Value),
                                  x = Single.Parse(l.Attribute("x").Value),
                                  y = Single.Parse(l.Attribute("y").Value),
                                  z = Single.Parse(l.Attribute("z").Value),
                                  Distance =  Single.Parse(l.Attribute("Distance").Value)
                              }).ToList()
              }).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

What I want to do now is:

I need to get closest number (value of `Current` from `Profile class) to let's say number 10.

*Example 1* If I have Numbers on `list 1,4,7,12,20`  correct result should be 7.

*Example 28* If I have Numbers on `list 1,21,22,44`   correct result should be 1.

I have managed that with following code:

```
var ProperLevel = GPSSpots.Where(s => s.Current < 10).Max(s => s.Current);
```

Now that I have that I will have to get corresponding data from class `Location` like:
Pull node with `Current` value we got from from class `Profile` and 
retreive `ID` from `Location` which has lowest `Distance`.

*Example:* Let say our var `ProperLevel` returns `2` (like in our XML which has only one node).
Now we have to pull correct node from Class `Locations` (corresponding var `ProperLevel`).
Now that we have the data we sort it based on lowest `Distance` and return `ID` of.

So based on our XML result should be:

```
Current level = 2
ID = 3
Distance = 43
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some options you can choose to get object having maximum/minimum of certain property value :

[How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

One of the shortest option available is using `Aggregate()` :

```
var ProperLevel = GPSSpots.Where(s => s.Current < 10)
                          .Aggregate((c, d) => c.Current > d.Current ? c : d);
var loc = ProperLevel.Location
                     .Aggregate((c, d) => c.Distance < d.Distance ? c : d);

Console.WriteLine("Current level = {0}", ProperLevel.Current);
Console.WriteLine("ID = {0}", loc.id);
Console.WriteLine("Distance = {0}", loc.Distance);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var loc = ProperLevel.Locations.Min(l=>l.Distance);

loc.Id...
loc.Distance
```