# Possible to return two fields from a Minimum Lambda expression?

Tags: c#, lambda

Is it possible to use a Lambda expression to return the minimum value of one field (ProgramQuantity) in a List of a custom class and another field(Program Price) in that class? If so, what might it look like?

```
decimal listMinQty = 0;
     List<PriceLevel> TrackPrice = new List<PriceLevel>();

        // add data to list here ...

        listMinQty = TrackPrice.Min(c => c.ProgramQuantity);// CAN I RETURN more than ProgramQuantity?

    }
            public class PriceLevel
    {
        public decimal ProgramPrice         { get; set; }
        public int ProgramQuantity          { get; set; }
        public DateTime ProgramLastTime     { get; set; }// Last Order Time
    }
```

Comment: In your specific example you could order by ProgramQuantity Descending and use `.Take` to return the first 3 results.  Do you need it to be more general than that?`TrackPrice.OrderByDescending(c => c.ProgramQuantity).Take(3)`

Comment: Currently your question isn't clear.  If you want the item that has the minimum `ProgramQuanity` value you need to specifically say that and then you'd need to tell us how to break potential ties if more than one item has the same minimum value for `ProgramQuantity`.

Comment: My mistake. corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to find the item for which you get the `Min`, you could do it like this:

```
var minItem = TrackPrice.OrderBy(c => c.ProgramQuantity).First();
```

Now you can take `minItem.ProgramQuantity` and `minItem.ProgramPrice`.

You could also use [`MinBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/914198/335858) extension to avoid sorting:

```
var minItem = TrackPrice.MinBy(c => c.ProgramQuantity);
var minQty = minItem.ProgramQuantity;
var priceOfMin = minItem.ProgramPrice;
```

Comment: Is it possible to update the List using minItem.ProgramPrice & minItem.ProgramQuantity like:minItem.ProgramPrice = loopLastPrice;

Comment: @Greg Since `PriceLevel` is a mutable `class`, the answer is "yes". Note, however, that it would not be possible if `PriceLevel` were a `struct`.

Comment: That's what I was looking for.  Thanks all