# Select records with max property value per group

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I've got a data set like this:

```
GroupName   GroupValue   MemberName   MemberValue
'Group1'    1            'Member1'    1
'Group1'    1            'Member2'    2
'Group2'    2            'Member3'    3
'Group2'    2            'Member4'    2
'Group3'    2            'Member5'    4
'Group3'    2            'Member6'    1
```

What I want to select is the rows that have the maximum `MemberValue` per `GroupName`, but only for those `GroupName`s that have the largest `GroupValue`, and pass them into a delegate function. Like this:

```
'Group2'    2            'Member3'    3
'Group3'    2            'Member5'    4
```

So far I've tried this format...

```
data.Where(maxGroupValue => 
    maxGroupValue.GroupValue == data.Max(groupValue => groupValue.GroupValue))
.Select(FunctionThatTakesData)
```

...but that just gives me every member of Group2 and Group3. I've tried putting a `GroupBy()` before the `Select()`, but that turns the output into an `IGrouping<string, DataType>` so `FunctionThatTakesData()` doesn't know what to do with it, and I can't do another `Where()` to filter out only the maximum `MemberValue`s.

What can I do to get this data set properly filtered and passed into my function?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do that with the following Linq.

```
var results = data.GroupBy(r = r.GroupValue)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Key)
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.GroupBy(r => r.GroupName)
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(r => r.MemberValue).First());
```

First you have to group on the `GroupValue` then order the groups in descending order by the `Key` (which is the `GroupValue`) and take the first one.  Now you have all the rows with the max `GroupValue`.  Then you group those on the `GroupName` and from those groups order the `MemberValue` in descending order and take the `First` row to get the row in each `GroupName` group with the max `MemberValue`.  Also I'm using the C# 6 null conditional operator `?.` after `FirstOrDefault` in case `data` is empty.  If you're not using C# 6 then you'll need to handle that case up front and you can just use `First` instead.

With the addition of `MaxBy` in .Net 6 this can now be done as follows

```
var results = data.GroupBy(r = r.GroupValue)
    .MaxBy(g => g.Key)
    ?.GroupBy(r => r.GroupName)
    .Select(g => g.MaxBy(r => r.MemberValue));
```

Comment: Thank you! Now, suppose each grouping can have multiple members with the same value... should I just use a `Where()` in place of the `First()`?

Comment: In that case you'd want `.SelectMany(g => g.GroupBy(r => r.MemberValue).OrderByDescending(sg => sg.Key).First())` to replace the last line.

Comment: Genius! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

So basically what you want, is to divide your data elements into groups with the same value for `GroupName`. From every group you want to take one element, namely the one with the largest value for property `MemberValue`.

Whenever you have a sequence of items, and you want to divide this sequence into groups based on the value of one or more properties of the items in the sequence you use [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

'GroupBy' takes your sequence as input and an extra input parameter: a function that selects which properties of your items you want to compare in your decision in which group you want the item to appear.

In your case, you want to divide your sequence into groups where all elements in a group have the same `GroupName`.

```
var groups = mySequence.GroupBy(element => element.GroupName);
```

What it does, it takes from every element in mySequence the property GroupName, and puts this element into a group of elements that have this value of GroupName.

Using your example data, you'll have three groups:

- The group with all elements with GroupName == "Group1". The first two elements of your sequence will be in this group
- The group with all elements with GroupName == "Group2". The third and fourth element of your sequence will be in this group
- The group with all elements with GroupName == "Group3". The last two elements of your sequence will be in this group

Each group has a property Key, containing your selection value. This key identifies the group and is guaranteed to be unique within your collection of groups. So you'll have a group with Key == "Group1", a group with Key == "Group2", etc.

Besides the `Key`, every group is a sequence of the elements in the group (note: the group **IS** an enumerable sequence, not: it **HAS** an enumerable sequence.

Your second step would be to take from every group the element in the group with the largest value for `MemberValue`. For this you would order the elements in the group by descending value for property MemberValue and take the first one.

```
var myResult = mySequence.GroupBy(element => element.GroupName)
    // intermediate result: groups where all elements have the same GroupName
    .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(groupElement => groupElement.MemberValue)
    // intermediate result: groups where all elements are ordered in descending memberValue
    .First();
```

Result: from every group ordered by descending memberValue, take the first element, which should be the largest one.

It is not very efficient to order the complete group, if you only want the element with the largest value for memberValue. The answer for this can be found
[here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

Comment: That gives you each `GroupName` with the max `MemberValue`.  The OP wants only the rows with the max `GroupValue` and then each `MemberName` with the max `MemberValue`.

Answer (score 2):

The easier way to solve this problem is to use the new (.NET 6) [`MaxBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby) LINQ operator, along with the [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) and [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) operators:

```
IEnumerable<Record> query = records
    .GroupBy(x => x.GroupName)
    .Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x.MemberValue));
```

This is an easy but not memory efficient solution. The reason is because it generates a full blown [`Lookup<TKey, TSource>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.lookup-2) structure under the hood, which is a dictionary-line container that contains all the records associated with each key. This structure is generated before starting to compare the elements contained in each grouping, in order to select the maximum element.

In most cases this inefficiency is not a problem, because the records are not that many, and they are already stored in memory. But if you have a truly deferred enumerable sequence that contains a humongous number of elements, you might run out of memory. In this case you could use the `GroupMaxBy` operator below. This operator stores in memory only the currently maximum element per key:

```
/// <summary>
/// Groups the elements of a sequence according to a specified key selector
/// function, and then returns the maximum element in each group according to
/// a specified value selector function.
/// </summary>
public static IEnumerable<TSource> GroupMaxBy<TSource, TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    Func<TSource, TValue> valueSelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> keyComparer = default,
    IComparer<TValue> valueComparer = default)
{
    // Arguments validation omitted
    valueComparer ??= Comparer<TValue>.Default;
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, (TSource Item, TValue Value)>(keyComparer);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        var key = keySelector(item);
        var value = valueSelector(item);
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var existing) &&
            valueComparer.Compare(existing.Value, value) >= 0) continue;
        dictionary[key] = (item, value);
    }
    foreach (var entry in dictionary.Values)
        yield return entry.Item;
}
```

Usage example:

```
IEnumerable<Record> query = records
    .GroupMaxBy(x => x.GroupName, x => x.MemberValue);
```

The reverse `GroupMinBy` can be implemented similarly by replacing the `>=` with `<=`.

Below is a demonstration of the difference in memory-efficiency between the two approaches:

```
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, 1_000_000);
{
    var mem0 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
    source.GroupBy(x => x % 1000).Select(g => g.MaxBy(x => x % 3333)).Count();
    var mem1 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
    Console.WriteLine($"Allocated: {mem1 - mem0:#,0} bytes");
}
{
    var mem0 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
    source.GroupMaxBy(x => x % 1000, x => x % 3333).Count();
    var mem1 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
    Console.WriteLine($"Allocated: {mem1 - mem0:#,0} bytes");
}
```

Output:

```
Allocated: 8,571,168 bytes
Allocated: 104,144 bytes
```

[Try it on Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CvBtE6).