# Use linq in the where clause

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 tables `_customerRepository.GetAllQueryable()` and  `_customerSettlementRepository.GetAllQueryable()`.

In table  `_customerSettlementRepository.GetAllQueryable()`, I have column `ApplyD (date)`, after joining these two together, I want to find out max `ApplyD` in the where clause. This is my code:

```
var settlements = from c in _customerRepository.GetAllQueryable()
    join cs in _customerSettlementRepository.GetAllQueryable() on new {c.CustomerMainC, c.CustomerSubC}
    equals new {cs.CustomerMainC, cs.CustomerSubC} into c1
    where cs.ApplyD == (c1.Select(b=>b.ApplyD).Max())
    select new CustomerSettlementViewModel()
    {
            TaxRate = cs.TaxRate
    };
```

Comment: add example input and output

Comment: Question is not very clear, waht do you want exactly ?

Comment: Simplify your query. If the LINQ query looks ugly, the generated SQL and performance will *also* be ugly. You won't be able to maintain this code in the future either

Comment: Furthermore, you are using an ORM, not writing SQL. If you have to use joins, you have a serious design bug. Your customer and customer *entities* should have navigation properties that point to each other. That's what LINQ and EF offer. If you end up using joins, what's the point of using LINQ at all?

Comment: Yes, I understand, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's remarkable that quite often in these questions people come up with an SQL(-like) statement without specification of the goal they want to reach. Hence it is impossible to see whether the provided statement fulfills the requirements.

Anyway, it seems you have something like `Customers` (in `CustomerRepository`) and `CustomerSettlements` in `CustomerSettlementRepository`.

both `Customers` and `CustomerSettlements` have a CustomerMainC and a CustomerSubC. You want to join `Customers` and `CustomerSettlements` on these two properties.

A `CustomerSettlement` also has an `ApplyD` and a `TaxRate`.

You only want to keep the join results where `ApplyD` has the maximum value of `ApplyD`

Finally, from every remaining join result you want to create one `CustomerSettlementViewModel` object with the value of the TaxRate in the join result that was taken from the `CustomerSettlement`.

Now that I wrote this, it baffles me why you need to join in the first place, because you only use values from the CustomerSettlements, not from the Customer.

Besides, if two Customers are joined with the same CustomerSettlements. this will result in two equal CustomerSettlementViewModel objects.

But let's assume this is really what you want.

In baby steps:

```
IQueryable<Customer> customers = ...
IQueryable<CustomerSettlement> customerSettlements = ...

var joinResults = customers.Join(customerSettlements
   customer => new {customer.CustomerMainC, customer.CustomerSubC},
   settlement => new {settlement.CustomerMainC, settlement.CustomerSubC}
   (customer, settlement) => new
   {
      settlement.ApplyD,
      settlement.TaxRate,
      // add other properties from customers and settlements you want in the end result
   });
```

In words: take all `Customers` and all `CustomerSettlements`. From every `Customer` create an object having the values of the customer's `CustomerMainC` and `CustomerSubC`. Do the same from every `CustomerSettlement`. When these two objects are equal, create a new object, having the values of the `CustomerSettlement`'s `ApplyD` and `TaxRate` (and other properties you need in the end result)

Note that this is still an IQueryable. No query is performed yet.

From this `joinResult` you only want to keep those objects that have the value of ApplyD that equals the maximum value of ApplyD.

[This question on StackOverflow is about selecting the records with the max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804896/linq-select-records-with-max-property-value-per-group). The idea is to group the records into groups with the same value for `ApplyD`. Then order the groups in descending Key order and take the  first group.

```
var groupsWithSameApplyD = joinResults.GroupBy(
    joinedItem => joinedItem.ApplyD,
    joinedItem => new CustomerSettlementViewModel()
    {
        TaxRate = orderedItem.TaxRate,
        // add other values from joinedItems as needed
    });
```

Every group in groupsWithSameApplyD has a key equal to ApplyD. The group consists of CustomerSettlementViewModel objects created frome the joinedItems that all have the same ApplyD that is in the `Key` of the group.

Now order by descending:

```
var orderedGroups = groupsWithSameApplyD.OrderByDescending(group => group.Key);
```

The first group contains all elements that had the largest ApplyD. Your desired result is the sequence of elements in the group.

If there is no group at all, return an empty sequence. Note if a sequence is requested as result, it is always better to return an empty sequence instead of null, so callers can use the returned value in a foreach without having to check for null return

```
var result = orderedGroups.FirstOrDefault() ??
    // if no groups at all, return empty sequence:
    Enumerable.Empty<CustomerSettlementViewModel>();
```

Note: the `FirstOrDefault` is the first step where the query is actually performed. If desired you could put everything in one big query. Not sure if this would improve readability and maintainability.

Comment: Thank you very much Harald Coppoolse, this is very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is my syntet error, I need to write this since the first

```
var settlements = from c in _customerRepository.GetAllQueryable()
                    join cs in _customerSettlementRepository.GetAllQueryable() on new {c.CustomerMainC, c.CustomerSubC}
                        equals new {cs.CustomerMainC, cs.CustomerSubC} 
                    select new CustomerSettlementViewModel()
                    {
                        TaxRate = cs.TaxRate
                    };
                settlements = settlements.Where(p => p.ApplyD == settlements.Max(b => b.ApplyD));
```

Comment: Please edit your question if you want to add more information.