# C# - Return object with lowest value in List

Tags: c#, list, min

I want to return the `User` where the amount is the lowest.

```
List<User> users = new List<User>();
users.Add(new User("Patrick", 39m));
users.Add(new User("Claude", 13.7m));
users.Add(new User("Steven", -45.3m));    

Decimal lowest = users.Min(user => user.Amount); //this gives me -45.3m
```

However what I need is *not* `-45.3m`, I need  `User{"Steven", -45.3m}`

Comment: Sort by amount and take the first object in the new collection.

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff yes that's what I have done already and this works perfectly, but I want to write it cleaner like the example I give with Decimal.

Comment: What did you search for? I googled "linq select lowest object in list" and this is the first result: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this... just loop through the list and find the smallest amount.

```
User lowest = users[0];
foreach(User u in users){
    if(u.Amount < lowest.Amount)
       lowest = u;
}
```

Comment: The link Jack Marchetti provided in your original question should get you on the right track..  I just added this answer here as an alternative way to go about it.. And if people want to down vote me, it's really no sweat off my back.  I'm just out trying to help.