# How can I to filter a List of objects by the first occurrences of a List of properties?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, optimization

Let's say I have the following code:

```
private class AccountRecord : IEquatable<AccountRecord>, IComparable<AccountRecord>
    {
        public Guid accountid { get; set; }
        public string accountnumber { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public Guid ownerid { get; set; }
        public string owneridtype { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public string companyname { get; set; }
        public AccountRecord(Guid accountid, string accountnumber, string name, Guid ownerid, string owneridtype, int number, string companyname)
        {
            this.accountid = accountid;
            this.accountnumber = accountnumber;
            this.name = name;
            this.ownerid = ownerid;
            this.owneridtype = owneridtype;
            this.number = number;
            this.companyname = companyname;
        }
        public bool Equals(AccountRecord other)
        {
            if(this.name.Equals(other.name) && this.number == other.number){
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public int CompareTo(AccountRecord other)
        {
            if (this.number > other.number)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (this.number < other.number)
            {
                return -1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Somewhere else I have a List of these objects:

```
private List<AccountRecord> accountRecords = new List<AccountRecord>();
```

And I add several objects to the list:

```
accountRecords.Add(new AccountRecord(
                Row.accountid, 
                Row.accountnumber, 
                name, 
                Row.ownerid, 
                Row.owneridtype, 
                number,
                companyname));
```

I then get a list of distinct values for the 'companyname' property.

```
List<string> distinctCompanynames = accountRecords.Distinct(x => x.companyname).ToList<string>();
```

I'd like to get a List of AccountRecord objects with the highest 'number' property for each distinct 'companyname' property. Thanks to the work that I have done, I can do this with a nested for loop but my entire approach doesn't seem like the best approach considering all the tools C# has at it's disposal. This list will eventually get very large and this code will be executed frequently so I must do this as efficiently as possible. How can I do this faster/better than my current method?

My current method is:

1. Make List of AccountRecords
2. Sort
3. (Reverse) Rewriting the CompareTo method of AccountRecord can remove this step.
4. Make List of distinct 'companyname' values in List of AccountRecords
5. Hard-code a nested for loop to perform some action on the first existence of an AccountRecord with each distinct 'companyname'.

What I'd like the method to be:

1. Make List of AccountRecords
2. Get a new list (or filter this list into becoming) a List of AccountRecord objects with the highest 'number' property for each distinct 'companyname' property.

If you have any questions, then please let me know.

Comment: Did you mean to use `Distinct` instead `Select` when selecting distinct companies?

Comment: Yes. I'll make an edit to my post. Thank you for noticing that.

Comment: `GroupBy`, then [reduce to solved problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/).

Comment: I think the first question should be are using Linq in reference to Entity Framework and afraid to narrow scope by frequent database calls?  If so you can do 'exists' and 'contains' of even more complex methods inside the context before it gets realized to a proper object.  If not and you already have your objects or are using an ADO.NET or other data retrieval just get your list as needed and then manipulate from that other sets.  EG: var data = thing.ToList();  var grouping = data.Select( operations...);  var filter = data.Exists(x => x.Contains(something...));

Comment: This type of filtering is not an option. The records do not exist with 'number' or 'companyname' in the data source. I am trying to do this by changing the data source architecture as little as possible. The data source is Microsoft Dynamics 365, so SQL queries are not permitted. You're right though, it is ideal for the data to be filtered as much as possible prior to processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but this should work:

```
from ac in accountRecords
group ac by ac.companyname into company
select new
{
    Company = company.Key,
    Number = company.OrderByDescending(g => g.number).FirstOrDefault()
}
```

UPDATE:  Read the question a bit more closely.  It can be simplifed:

```
List<AccountRecord> highestRecords = 
   (from ac in accountRecords
    group ac by ac.companyname into company
    select company.OrderByDescending(g => g.number).FirstOrDefault())
   .ToList();
```

Comment: I am not familiar with from/group/select. What must I be 'using' for that to compile?

Comment: @MichaelDrum Just `System.Linq` which you should already be including,

Comment: Thank you for the edit you made. I'm new to Linq so I needed more context. I can't wait to see if it works.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for your solution @James. I particularly like how simple and easy it is to understand.