# Take list of unique by name Presidents with the oldest date of Governance (if name repeated)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` of `Presidents`:

```
var obj = new List<President>();
```

They have fields `Name` and `BeginningGovernance`. 
The `Name` can be repeated in list. The `BeginningGovernance` cann't repeat.
I need take `List` of unique by `Name` Presidents with the *oldest* `BeginningGovernance` (if name repeated).

How can I do this with help of *Linq*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `GroupBy`:

1. Group by `Name`
2. Pick up the right president among ones with the *same* `Name`
3. Materialize to `List` "I need take list..."

Implementation:

```
var result = obj
  .GroupBy(president => president.Name)
  .Select(chunk => chunk // among presidents who have the same name
     .OrderBy(president => president.BeginningGovernance)
     .First())
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Great! But I need use **OrderBy** that to take him first time of governance (the oldest)

Comment: @Михаил Тарасов: `OrderByDescending` sort the presidents in reversed order (the oldest will be the first)

Comment: `(...).ToList()`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, I'm ask about his **first time** of governance. 
The last date is the one that is closer to the present time (we need OrderByDescending sort the presidents in reversed order). 
But the **first time** - the **oldest date** (we need sort OrderBy to take First).
My english is not very good. It may be difficulties of translation.

Comment: I see, I am sorry for my misunderstanding, it should be `OrderBy` then

Comment: The OrderBy in this case is likely to be cheap, since the list of collisions is going to be very short. But in cases where the list of collisions is very long, you're doing a lot of work to sort a list in order to take only the smallest element.  A more efficient query would use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value  and then you get `obj.GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(g => g.MinBy(p => p.BeginningGovernance)).ToList()` which is both more efficient in the asymptotic case, and easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is fine. I'll just point out that you could write a query that is shorter and easier to understand by using this code:

https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/8fbb540fd140b6d0008120c37abd00e129203cc6/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs

Your query would then be

```
presidents
  .OrderBy(p => p.BeginningGovernance)
  .DistinctBy(p => p.Name)
  .ToList()
```

which is extremely easy to read and understand.

Exercise:  Suppose we swapped the order of the OrderBy and DistinctBy; would the query still be correct? Why or why not?

Comment: Yes, it will work correctly, but by the condition of the task, sorting by BeginningGovernance is not required :)

Comment: @МихаилТарасов: That the result be thus sorted is not required. But do you see why in my solution to the problem, the order-by is *required*, and *required to be first*?

Comment: Yes I understand your solution and it's ok.