# How to find an element with the lowest value by using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of elements. I want to find the lowest value from these elements but they have no property, I have to calculate the value and compare it first.

My pseudo code:

```
        int currentLowestValue = int.MaxValue;
        MyObj targetElement = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++)
        {
            MyObj ele = elements[i];
            int val = ele.CalculateValue() + GetOtherValue();

            if (val < currentLowestValue)
            {
                targetElement = ele;
                currentLowestValue = val;
            }
        }
```

How can I select the element with the lowest value calculated out of `ele.CalculateValue() + GetOtherValue();` by using Linq?

Comment: What is `MyObj `? How can __you__ tell its lowest value? You may have to `Cast<>` it..

Comment: Will GetOtherValue() return different values in the loop?

Comment: Use the LINQ `Min` extension method and lambdas.

Comment: why is lowest value assign to int.MaxValue

Comment: This is typically done with `OrderBy` and `First` or alternatively MoreLinq has a `MinBy` method you can use.

Comment: @saviour123 So that the first comparison will be true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an anonymous type to store the result of the calculation and the object.

```
int otherVal = GetOtherValue(); // why you calculated it in the loop?
var lowestValObj = elements
    .Select(x => new { MyObj = x, Value = x.CalculateValue() + otherVal})
    .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
    .First();
MyObj targetElement = lowestValObj.MyObj;
int lowestVal = lowestValObj.Value;
```

Comment: One reason to call GetOtherValue inside the loop would be if it did not return the same value every call.

Comment: @PaulF: maybe, then it's easy to replace `otherVal` with `GetOtherValue()`

Comment: Just answering your comment - but as you suggest, if the value is unchanging then it would be better to calculate it the once.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/914109/1260204)

```
MyObj targetElement = elements.Aggregate((curMin, x) => (curMin == null || x.CalculateValue() < curMin.CalculateValue() ? x : curMin));
int currentLowestValue = targetElement.CalculateValue() + GetOtherValue();
```

As the value of `GetOtherValue()` *seems* to be static (unchanging) you do not need it in the calculation to find the element with the smallest value. If this method is not idempotent then you would need to add it to the loop and cache the results in the aggregate.