# Keep distinct value in List depending on condition

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list where I'm applying the following condition with linQ:

I want to select all items where Name contains a certain string.

```
var nameFilter = result
                     .Where(e => e.Name.Contains(requestedValue))
                     .ToList();
```

At the end, sometimes it happens that I am having a list with repeated names:

For example:

```
requestedValue = 'form';
```

I end up with:

```
Name           Price
transformer    100
transformer    20 
formation      340
former         201
```

I got `transformer` twice. In that case, I want to only leave transformer with the **least price** : `20`

How could I do this with linQ without looping?

Comment: Your data looks like it could be in a Dictionary instead of a List structure

Comment: @mikaelmendoza21 my list has way more attributes I just put these to showcase what I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of [`GroupBy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) method

```
 var nameFilter = result.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(requestedValue))
    .GroupBy(k=>k.Name, g=>g.Price, (k,g)=>new Model {Name = k, Price = g.Min()})
    .ToList();
```

where `new Model` should be changed to your class name.

If you have more properties to return probably it will be more convenient to do

```
 var nameFilter = result.Where(e => e.Name.Contains(requestedValue))
            .GroupBy(k => k.Name, g => g, (k, g) =>
            {
                var minPrice = g.Min(x => x.Price);
                return g.First(x => x.Price == minPrice);
            }).ToList();
```

Finding `minPrice` and finding the item with `minPrice` can be done is a single for loop or, for example, by using following discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)