# compare objects inside a list according to their property value

Tags: c#, list

In order to do a XML Serialization, I implemented this structure

```
[XmlRoot("NXRoutes")]
public class NXRoutes
{
    [XmlElement("NXRoute")]
    public List<NXRoute> NXRoute { get; set; }
}

public class NXRoute
{
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Path")]
    public List<Path> Path { get; set; }
}

public class Path
{
    [XmlAttribute("Nbr_R")]
    public int R_count { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("ID")]
    [XmlAttribute("Preferred")]
    public string Preferred { get; set; }
}
```

in each element of my list `NXRoute` i would like to make comparison between the elements of the list `Path` and this comparison is based on the value of the integer attribute `R_Count`

==> For example for the path that has the smallest value in its attribute "R_Count" I would do a calculation / and for others I would do another calculation

how can i implement this comparison to do some calculation on the path element ?

example of calculation (for more details):
after comparaison :

- for the path with the smallest attribute `R_Count` i will puth it's attribute `Preferred="YES"`
- For the other paths put their attribute `Preferred="NO"`

Comment: Could you provide an example of the type of calculation you are trying to do?

Comment: @laptou i edited the question

Comment: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value) can be helpful I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could do this using LINQ:

```
// Assuming nxRoutes is your NXRoutes object
foreach (var route in nxRoutes.NXRoute)
{
    var paths = route.Path.OrderBy(p => p.R_count).ToArray();
    // This will return a list of paths ordered by the count
    // This means the first one is the smallest
    paths[0].Preferred = "YES";

    // Set the others to NO
    for (int i = 1; i < paths.Length; i++)
    {
        paths[i].Preferred = "NO";
    }
}
```