# Get the highest date in a List of object and get another property of its class

Tags: c#

I have a class that is like this:

```
class DateTimeProperty
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public DateTime TDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and I use it like so:

```
List<DateTimeProperty> dtp = new List<DateTimeProperty>();
```

and I fill the list like so:

```
var item = new DateTimeProperty
{
   Id = id,
   TDateTime = transactioDateTime
};
dtp.Add(item);
```

Then I get the maximum date like so

```
maxDate = dtp.Max(x => x.TDateTime);
```

but what I need is the Id that has that date. Can you please show me how to get this? The whole code is below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<DateTimeProperty> dtp = new List<DateTimeProperty>();
    var format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff";
    var folderPath = @"I:\LCS Transactions";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    List<DateTime> dateTimeArray = new List<DateTime>();
    DateTime maxDate;
    FileInfo[] fi = di.GetFiles();

    foreach(FileInfo f in fi)
    {
        var file = GetHeader(f.FullName);

        if (!file.Contains(".txt"))
        {
            if (file.Contains("_"))
            {
                var spike = file.Split('_');
                var transactionType = spike[0];
                var dateTime = spike[3];
                var id = spike[4];
                var year = dateTime.Substring(0, 4);
                var month = dateTime.Substring(4, 2);
                var day = dateTime.Substring(6,2);
                var hour = dateTime.Substring(8, 2);
                var minute = dateTime.Substring(10, 2);
                var seconds = dateTime.Substring(12, 2);
                var miiliseconds = dateTime.Substring(14, 3);
                var stringDate = $@"{day}/{month}/{year} {hour}:{minute}:{seconds}.{miiliseconds}";

                DateTime transactioDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

                var item = new DateTimeProperty
                {
                    Id = id,
                    TDateTime = transactioDateTime
                };

                Console.WriteLine(transactioDateTime);

                //dateTimeArray.Add(transactioDateTime);
                dtp.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }

            maxDate = dtp.Max(x => x.TDateTime);
            Console.WriteLine("=====================");
            Console.WriteLine(maxDate);

            Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Should anything special happen if there are 2 or more items with the same maximum `TDateTime` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just order by the date and take the Id property from the first item:

```
var maxDateId = dtp
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.TDateTime)
    .FirstOrDefault()?.Id;
```

`FirstOrDefault` can return `null` if the sequence is empty, which is why I use the null conditional operator (`?.`) to access the `Id` property. If the sequence is empty, `maxDateId` will be null, so you might have to check for this to make your code safe from a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use `OrderByDescending`, then `FirstOrDefault`

```
var result = dtp.OrderByDescending(x => TDateTime).FirstOrDefault();

if(result != null)
   Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Enumerable.OrderByDescending Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in descending order.

[Enumerable.FirstOrDefault Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Returns the first element of a sequence, or a default value if no
>   element is found.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid paying the performance price of sorting the list by using the LINQ [Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netframework-4.7.2) method.

```
var maxDateItem = dtp.Aggregate((DateTimeProperty)null, (max, item) =>
{
    return max == null || item.TDateTime > max.TDateTime ? item : max;
});
var maxDateItemId = maxDateItem.Id; // Will throw if the list has no elements
```

---

**Update.** More solutions here: [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value).