# How to get each student's highest Score, in order

Tags: c#, linq

I have Student class and the initialized list of students to the Program class in my project.
Now I want to get the highest score of each student, in order

How to get that using `Max()`?

```
public class Student
{
    public string First { get; set; }

    public string Last { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public List<int> Scores;
} 

// Create a data source by using a collection initializer.

static List<Student> students = new List<Student>
{
   new Student {First="Svetlana", Last="Omelchenko", ID=111, Scores= new List<int> {97, 92, 81, 60}},
   new Student {First="Claire", Last="O’Donnell", ID=112, Scores= new List<int> {75, 84, 91, 39}},
   new Student {First="Sven", Last="Mortensen", ID=113, Scores= new List<int> {88, 94, 65, 91}},
   new Student {First="Cesar", Last="Garcia", ID=114, Scores= new List<int> {97, 89, 85, 82}},
   new Student {First="Debra", Last="Garcia", ID=115, Scores= new List<int> {35, 72, 91, 70}},
   new Student {First="Fadi", Last="Fakhouri", ID=116, Scores= new List<int> {99, 86, 90, 94}},
   new Student {First="Hanying", Last="Feng", ID=117, Scores= new List<int> {93, 92, 80, 87}},
   new Student {First="Hugo", Last="Garcia", ID=118, Scores= new List<int> {92, 90, 83, 78}},
   new Student {First="Lance", Last="Tucker", ID=119, Scores= new List<int> {68, 79, 88, 92}},
   new Student {First="Terry", Last="Adams", ID=120, Scores= new List<int> {99, 82, 81, 79}},
   new Student {First="Eugene", Last="Zabokritski", ID=121, Scores= new List<int> {96, 85, 91, 60}},
   new Student {First="Michael", Last="Tucker", ID=122, Scores= new List<int> {94, 92, 91, 91} }
};
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? If you haven't tried anything: start with `students.Select`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var studScores=students.Select(x=>new 
            {
                student=x,
                highestscore=x.Scores.DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max()
            }).OrderByDescending(m=>m.highestscore);

            foreach(var score in studScores)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(score.highestscore+" "+score.student.First);
            }
```

**Output**

```
99 Fadi
99 Terry
97 Svetlana
97 Cesar
96 Eugene
94 Sven
94 Hichael
93 Hanying
92 Hugo
92 Lance
91 Claire
91 Debra
```

Comment: And `x.Scores.DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max()` would be better since you can get `System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements` if you call `.Max()` on an empty collection.

Answer (score -2):

Traversing students and then using the bubble sorting algorithm to maximize

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Student> students = new List<Student>();
        students.Add(new Student { First = "Svetlana", Last = "Omelchenko", ID = 111, Scores = new List<int> { 97, 92, 81, 60 } });
        students.Add(new Student { First = "Svetlana", Last = "Omelchenko", ID = 111, Scores = new List<int> { 75, 84, 91, 39 } });

        for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
        {
            Student item = students[i];
            List<int> scores = item.Scores;
            int max = SortGetMax(scores);
            Debug.WriteLine(max);
        }
    }

    public static int SortGetMax(List<int> arrays)
    {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
        {
            if (arrays[i] > max)
            {
                int flag = arrays[i];
                arrays[i] = max;
                max = flag;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: Why does `SortGetMax` mutate the input, and also not output the max? What is it supposed to do? If I call  `List<int> test = new List<int>() { 5, 3, 8, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9 }; var max = SortGetMax(test);`, the output is `8` when clearly it should be `9`. The values in `test` become `0, 3, 5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9` after executing your method, and after executing it a second time they become `0, 0, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 9`.

Comment: some mistake need change for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Count - 1; i++)  to for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)

Comment: That still leaves the issue of it mutating the original list in a bad way.

Comment: dont' reinvent the wheel. .Net has methods for sorting things, tested by .Net team and successfully used by thousands of developers. No need to write your own sorting algorithm, test it and fix bugs.