# How to find key in Dictionary<DateTime, DataTable> by using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary DateTime, DataTable

Key                     Values

2019/07/01              Column A  |  B

```
                  1 | 1
```

2019/07/02              Column A  |  B

```
                  3 | 4
```

2019/07/03              Column A  |  B

```
                  5 | 4
```

I would like to use linq to find the key of the dictionary with maximum value of column A in the dict.

In above case, my expected result is "2019/07/03"

I am new in linq. Is it possible for above use? How to do?

Comment: what is the key, what is the value? can you post dictionary definition?

Comment: `dict.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.A).FirstOrDefault()?.Key`

Comment: Please post this as a [mcve] to help people help you and get quicker and better answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `.OrderByDescending(x=> x.Key).FirstOrDefault()?.Key;` will give you the correct answer, it will result in first sorting the values which is time and memory inefficient.

What you want to do is scan all your values once without memory consumption:

```
 KeyValuePair<MyKey, MyValue> maxKey;
 if (list.Count > 0)
 {
    maxKey = list.Aggregate(list.First(), (first,second)=>first.Value.A>second.Value.A?first:second);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one example.

```
Dictionary<DateTime, int> example = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>() 
            { 
                {new DateTime(2019,07,01), 1 },
                {new DateTime(2019,07,02), 2 },
                {new DateTime(2019,07,03), 3 }
            };
var HighestKey = example.Keys.Max();
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below solution, I am sure it will work.

```
<DictionaryName>.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).First();
```

Comment: If the dictionary is empty, this code would throw an exception.