# How to avoid OrderByDescending in query linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have the linq query:

```
var ed = db.table
.GroupBy(x => x.Sn)
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

I need to rewrite this query for server-side evaluation.

My table:

```
Sn    Value      Data     
150   180.3    01/06/2020  
150   195.0    01/05/2020  
149   13.3     01/06/2020  
345   27.5     27/06/2013
....
```

Comment: What is the question here? what issue you are facing with this query? What error are you  getting?

Comment: If i execute this query I get this exception:
OrderByDescending(x => x.Date) could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: You need to sort Data by date as Descending?

Comment: i need select all objects with max date for each ID. I already asked a similar question here, but that answer work only client side. Unfortunately my table contains a lot of data and i can't afford client side evaluation.

Comment: Use two queries or write and execute raw query

Comment: Use a window function with PARTITION BY to group by the Sn column, then get the first row of each partition by using the ROW_NUMBER() function. This cannot be done with Linq

Answer (score 2):

```
.Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault())
```

is probably just:

```
.Select(g => g.Max(x => x.Date))
```

Which the parser probably handles better

Comment: Will it select max Date for each objects or max date in the table?

Comment: @disshell as written: the max in the group, which is the same thing as "order by descending, first or default"

Comment: Unfortunately, this query return IQueryable<DateTime>, but i need get full object from my table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Aggregate`

```
var ed = db.table
           .GroupBy(x => x.Sn)
           .Select(x => x.Aggregate((max, cur) => max.Date > cur.Date ? max : cur));
```

This might help you to know more [How to use LINQ to select object with minimum or maximum property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914109/how-to-use-linq-to-select-object-with-minimum-or-maximum-property-value).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether `dt.Table` is IQueryable or not.

Normally an IQueryable is to be executed by a different process, quite often a database management system. It that is the case, you'll have to use OrderBy followed by a FirstOrDefault.

Luckily proper database management systems are extremely optimized to sort. If you are not satisfied with the efficiency of the sort, and you don't change your table too often, consider adding an extra index in DbContext.OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .HasIndex(customer => customer.Name)
```

Your database management system knows this extra index, and can immediately return the element that the last item of the index refers to.

Whenever you change the name, or add a new Customer, the index has to be recreated. So don't do this if you are changing customer names often, like 10 times a second.

If `dt.table` is not IQueryable, but IEnumerable, OrderBy is relatively slow. Alas there is no Enumerable.Max for you, but you can use on of the overloads of [Enumerable.Aggregate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate?view=netcore-3.1).

As you are certain that every group contains at least one element, you can use the overload without Seed:

```
var result = db.table.GroupBy(x => x.Sn)
   .Aggregate( (maxItem, nextitem) =>(nextItem.Date > maxItem.Date) ?? nextItem : maxItem)
```

If you use this quite often, consider to create an extension method. Creating an extension method is quite easy. See [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

```
public static T MaxOrDefault<T, TProperty> MaxPropertyOrDefault(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<TSource, TProperty> propertySelector)
{
     return MaxPropertyOrDefault(source, propertySelector, null)
}
```

Overload with comparer: if comparer equals null, use default comparer

```
public static T MaxOrDefault<T, TProperty> MaxPropertyOrDefault(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<TSource, TProperty> propertySelector,
    IComparer<TProperty) comparer)
{
    // TODO: what to do if source == null?
    // TODO: what to do if propertySelector == null?
    if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<TProperty>.Default();
    
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
    if (!enumerator.MoveNext)
    {
        // empty source, return default:
        return default(T);
    }
    else
    {
        TProperty maxPropertyValue = propertySelector(enumerator.Current);
        T maxValue = enumerator.Current();

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
             TProperty currentPropertyValue = propertySelector(enumerator.Current);
             if (comparer.Compare(currentPropetyValue, maxPropertyValue) > 0)
             {
                 maxPropertyValue = currentPropertyValue;
                 maxValue = enumerator.Current;
             } 
        }
        return maxValue;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var ed = db.table.GroupBy(x => x.Sn)
           .Select(group => group.MaxOrDefault(groupElement => groupElement.Date);
```